# Git - Mege branch into master, if master was already merged into branch

Tags: git, git-merge

We have some bad things with our branches going on. 
It looks like that:

```
A------B------E------F------H    - master
       \              \
        \              \
         C------D-------G-----I  - develop
```

At the commit "F" we merged master into develop.
And now we need to merge develop into master. But obviously we will lose H commit. Is there any way to resolve this state of uncontrollable big boy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will not loose commit `H` by merging `dev` into `master`
To merge you could use below commands:

```
//switch to master
git checkout master

//merge
get merge dev
//this will not remove any commits you have done in master.
```

Your master branch now will be something like below:

```
ABCDEFGHI //Of course the order will be depending on order of commits you have done.
```